# Rails 4 + ActiveRecord: How to use .group to return an array of records and not just a single one?

Tags: activerecord

I have a `Product` model that `has_many` `ProductImage`s.

Each of those images has an attribute called `name`.

ex:

Product: T-shirt

T-shirt has images: `image1 name:blue`, `image2 name:blue`, `image3 name:green`

Is there a method in ActiveRecord to group all of `T-shirt`'s images into an array of arrays based on name? I want something that would return `[[image1, image2], [image3]]`, since image1 and image2 have the same color they are grouped into one array.

The docs (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) say `.group(:name)` wouldn't do what I want: "this will give you a single Order object for each date where there are orders in the database."

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you want, you may want to check out the Ruby Enumerable `group_by` method.  That will return a Hash and then you can get the `values`:

```
product_id = <T-Shirt Product ID Here>
ProductImage.where(product_id: product_id).group_by(&:name).values
```

This will give an array of arrays where the ProductImages are grouped together in the inner arrays by name.